# If a representation is irreducible iff $(\chi_V,\chi_V)=\sum_{i=1}^k a_i^2$, wouldn’t that mean that there’s only one $a_i$ and that $a_i=1$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, representation-theory, characters

If a representation $V$ of a group $G$ is irreducible iff $(\chi_V,\chi_V)=\sum_{i=1}^k a_i^2$=1, where $a_i$ is the multiciplity of each $V_i$ in the isotypic decomposition of $V$, wouldn’t that mean that there’s only one $a_i$ and $a_i$=1?

I’m obviously misunderstanding something. I thought that if $W$ is an irreducible representation of a group $G$, then it would appear as a term in the regular representation of $G$ with multiciplity equal to its dimension $\dim(W)$. But then I don’t see why we wouldn’t have $\dim(W)=1$ for all irreducible representations, which doesn’t seem to be the case… where is my confusion laying?

Comment: Are you assuming $G$ is abelian?

Comment: How did you conclude $\dim(W)=1$? The regular representation is clearly not irreducible.

Comment: Not sure where the confusion is. If $V$ is irreducible, then you are right, only one $a_i$ is nonzero (the one corresponding to $V$, precisely), and equal to $1$. But when you decompose the regular representation, the multiplicities are indeed equal to $\dim(W)$, but that's not a contradiction since the regular representation has no reason to be irreducible.

Comment: Oh okay, I don’t know why I thought the decomposition should be unique, and that’s why I concluded $\dim W = a_i$. Clearly misread something (I’m just learning about this topic). Thanks to everybody who commented.

Comment: First off, $(\chi_V,\chi_V)=\sum a_i^2$ is true for any rep $V$, irreducible or not. That means $V$ is irreducible iff $(\chi_V,\chi_V)=1$ because $V$ is irreducible iff all $a_i$ are $0$ except for one $a_j$ which is $1$. It's also true every irrep $W$ appears with multiplicity $\dim W$ in the regular rep. The regular rep is reducible. Of course, if you want to decompose the irrep $W$ into irreps, then the multiplicity of $W$ is **one**, not $\dim W$, and all other irreps have multiplicity $0$. You need to just keep track of what exactly it is you're decomposing.

Comment: @runway44 Sorry, that was a typo in the question. Should have written $(\chi_V,\chi_V)=1$. Thank you for the explanation.